# Why Doesn't Key Down Event Mask Work, but Mask All Does?

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, keyboard-events, cgeventtap

I have a basic keystroke converter app in development. The conversion works with the following:

```
CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = NULL;
CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, myCGEventCallback, NULL);
runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
```

As you might expect, `kCGEventMaskForAllEvents` is constantly firing for any mouse movement or click in addition to the keyboard, and I suspect tying up system resources. I tried substituting `CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown)`, which best I can tell from [Quartz Event doc on Event Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventType) is what I want, and would weed out mouse movements and clicks. Unfortunately, using this seems to just eat the keystrokes, rather than convert them.

What am I doing wrong?

The following works, but I still don't understand why `CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp)` by itself isn't the correct implementation.

```
CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(NX_SYSDEFINED)
```

Comment: I have been looking into this a bit and im not sure if this is the answer or not.  I also noticed when looking at your thing . NX_SYSDEFINED seems to not work for me

Answer (score 2):

because a keystroke *key press* consists of a keydown and a key up

Comment: So KeyDown and KeyUp aren't two separate events that can be detected independently? On iOS virtual buttons, I can detect touchUpInside as a different event from touchDown.

Answer (score 2):

1. The *discussion* section of the [`CGEventTapCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454426-cgeventtapcreate) doc page says:

   > Event taps receive key up and key down events if one of the following conditions is true:
   >
   > - The current process is running as the root user.
   > - Access for assistive devices is enabled. In OS X v10.4, you can enable this feature using System Preferences, Universal Access panel, Keyboard view.

   Running as the root user definitely worked for me (MacOS Sierra.) I didn't try the assistive devices approach.
2. To run as root inside XCode (I have 8.3.3 at this time), choose *Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme.../Run/Info/Debug Process As: root*

   [image: XCode's Edit Scheme dialog]
3. In the `CGEventTapCreate` call, replace the `kCGEventMaskForAllEvents` argument with `CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp)`.  Your callback will now get invoked for most key presses, except for modifier keys: shift, ctrl, cmd, some of teh function keys.

   To get the callback invoked for the modifier keys, add `CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp) | CGEventMaskBit(NX_SYSDEFINED)`.  For some reason, with this change I also get the callback invoked for mouse button presses.  This might be a side effect of how the Logitech mouse driver works -- I didn't investigate.  But the volume of calls is much lower than before and doesn't include mouse moves.

   [Dave Keck's response to this CocoaBuilder thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/242438-trouble-with-event-taps.html#242495) gets credit for figuring this out.

Comment: Running as a root user works perfectly. But it only works for debugging